# WordPress automatically adding extra -1 or slug postfix while updating a sub category item

Tags: permalinks

I have been encountered a problem that is -

When i am adding a sub category it fine and showing as expected but when i try to update that category again then slug automatically changed to another.

**Example:**

> Category name: `Lab` slug: `lab` & Sub category name: `Water lab`
>   slug: `water-lab`

When i open sub category water lab and hit update then slug changed to `water-lab-1` or sometimes it changed to `water-lab-lab`

I am running wordpress version - 4.4.2 and I've been running some number of plugins currently.

Comment: what is your "permalink" setting?, have you tried disabling plugin just to make sure?

Comment: permalink settings is set to: Custom structure - /articles/%postname%/ no didn't tried to disabled plugin

Answer (score 0):

Slugs are unique. You probably have a tag with slug "water-lab" so wordpress renames your Sub category. Please double check that there is not article, tag etc with the same slug

Comment: When I create a sub category and put name "test lab" and slug automatically create "test-lab" but when I go to edit mode again and update it slug does update as "test-lab-1" I hope you get it now

Comment: You have this problem with _all plugins_ disabled?

Comment: No, I need to test that with all plugin disabled that's the only option left for me. I never encountered that this kind of problem before